# Determining interop function caller

Tags: c#, vb6, interop

I'm exposing a C# class to COM using these attributes:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[GuidAttribute("2325EBEB-DB5F-4D29-B220-64845379D9C5")]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(WrapperEvents))]
```

in this class I have a function:

public void shutdownService()

This function is meant to be called just once from a VB6 client via COM Interop. Everything works fine. But somehow, it's being called more than once. My C# codes doesn't call this function directly. So I'm guessing the problem is in VB6 code. Unfortunately, that's not what the VB6 team thinks. 
Is there a way to determine the caller of this function, ie. from my C#code or the VB6 code?

Right now I'm using a simple function to get the stacktrace:

```
    public void LogStack()
    {
        var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
        foreach (var frame in trace.GetFrames())
        {
            var method = frame.GetMethod();
            if (method.Name.Equals("LogStack")) continue;
            logger.Debug(string.Format("LogStack: {0}::{1}",
                method.ReflectedType != null ? method.ReflectedType.Name : string.Empty, method.Name));
        }
    }
```

Obviously, I got somthing like this on the log:

```
2011-12-23 08:28:40,067 1          DEBUG (null) LogStack: Service::shutdownService
```

Since the only line of LogStack is the COM exposed function, I assume it's being called from vb6. But that's not enough proof for the VB6 team. Any idea how to really prove where function ?

Comment: Can you ask the VB6 team to add logging on their side?

Comment: Did that.. the response was "It's ok in my side.." VB6 apps is kinda legacy app which has changed developers so often that people are kinda lost track of it.. It sucks I know, but the cost in replacing it would be too high that we hold on to it..

Comment: can you add logging to anywhere in the vb app shutdownService is called, and keep the logging in the .net code and simply match timestamps? if you absolutely must know, you could throw an exception in there and try to intentionally get the caller to crash to become visible. Keep a static count and when its >1 (assuming something should only call it once) throw the exception. compuware had a product called truetime a while back that logged all activity while running. I dont believe thats around anymore though (plus would require an install on the client so assuming thats out)

Comment: Doh! I really don't know why I missed out on logging in the vb app.. That'll be helpful.. Thanks.. And also will try to use the StackWalk64..

Comment: Update: We finally agreed to remove vb6 calls to shutdownService, and see if it's still being called.. if it is, then it's on my .NET side.. Thanks, adam.

PS. failed to make stackwalk64 works. :D

Comment: Update: after removing vb6 calls to shutdownService, it's not being called anymore.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try several things:

- set a breakpoint in your code to trigger the debugger, then look at the call stack. 
  You could do an application dump here from visual studio and send it to them or screenshot the stack.

ex. Debugger.Break

http://www.netsplore.com/PublicPortal/blog.aspx?EntryID=12

Dump with "Savre Dump As"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx

- Use the com tracing 
  from a system level see
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926098

I also recall a tool being installed with visual studio 6 do to this as well

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention, the only way to really run my application is at customer site, since it requires a hardware that we don't posses. And there, we're not allowed to install visual studio.. Its company policy. It really tied up my hand.. Looking for a solution where it's on my COM side, where I can really control. Thanks for the link, will check it first to see if any ideas pop up :)

Comment: can you install the debugging tools for windows and grab a dump via code? Also consider stackwalker and calling off to managed cpp library http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxtoolsdev/thread/b05a9e86-c84b-42a7-a861-6c8e0e8cd40d